# Duplicate sessions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-state

I have a model:

```
<?php

class Loginfunctionmodel extends CI_Model{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();

    }

    # check_if_loggedin() below checks if user has session w/ loggedIn=1, then displays needed supernav elements
    function check_if_loggedin(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        # user has loggedin Val = 1 and valid session_id
        $loggedInSetSuccess = 1;
        $sess = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        $sessionsDbCompare = $this->db->get_where('Client',array('session_id'=>$sess,'loggedIn'=>$loggedInSetSuccess));
        // no session id for user in database... load login
        if($sessionsDbCompare->num_rows() == 1 ){
                $this->load->view('supernavigationloggedin.php');
                $this->load->view('primarynavigation.php');        
        }
        // otherwise problem with session count for the user is greater than 1.
        // Regenerate values
        elseif($sessionsDbCompare->num_rows() > 1){
            #remove current errorneous [session_id] data
                $this->session->unset_userdata();
            #reset [session_id] data
                $this->session->set_userdata();
            # load logged in views, given single session id exists.
                $this->load->view('supernavigationnotloggedin.php');
                $this->load->view('primarynavigation.php');               
        }

        // otherwise problem with session or loggedIn ... show login form.
        else{
            #remove current errorneous [session_id] data; load not logged in views.
            $this->session->unset_userdata();
            $this->load->view('supernavigationnotloggedin.php');
            $this->load->view('primarynavigation.php');     
        }

    }

}
?>
```

The problem is when I visit this page @ `localhost/mysite` it loads the following view : `homepage.php` and this model (above) called `homepagemodel.php` loads too, but a session is being created as soon as I load the page, how do I get it to be only `if{} block` is executed ? If I put it *inside* the `if{} block`, then a session will not be created in time using `$this->load->library('session');` .

Anyone? I've been trying various fixes for this, but it keeps making duplicate rows with duplicate session values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if this is what you need, but here we go...

```
function check_if_loggedin()
{        
    $is_logged = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');
    $sess = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
    $sessionsDbCompare = $this->db->get_where('Client',array('session_id'=>$sess));

    if ($is_logged == 1 && $sessionsDbCompare->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', 1);
        $this->load->view('supernavigationloggedin.php');
        $this->load->view('primarynavigation.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata();
        $this->load->view('supernavigationnotloggedin.php');
        $this->load->view('primarynavigation.php');  
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know that $is_logged == 1 will ever evaluate to '1' because the value of session->userdata() is either TRUE or FALSE; correct ?

Comment: The value of `$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')` is what you have setted. You can use TRUE or FALSE, or numbers like `1` or `0` as I have made at the line  `$this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', 1);`

Comment: the problem with this is loggedIn is NOT session value, but rather a column in db. Is there a way to add loggedIn to the session array which currently include the typical session_id, user_agent, etc. ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :(  But all the information setted with `set_userdata()` will be persisted in the db at `user_data` column only if you have enable CI to store sessions in database

Comment: So, what I'm trying to say is loggedIn column IS NOT part of the default session array e.g. set_userdata(); its a seperate column within the same table as the session data (e.g. set_userdata() ) does that make sense??

Comment: Yes, but what do you want now? Include `loggedIn` in the session array?

Comment: To set: `$this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', 1);` or `$this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', TRUE);`. To get: `$value = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');`